# How to evenly space columns using FlexBox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

We have a set of results that should be displayed in three columns. Using `Flexbox` we were able to get a majority of what we wanted to accomplished (i.e. All have the same height, properly aligned at the top (see `flex__top`, and properly aligned at the bottom (see `flex__bottom`).

However, we have ran into an issue where when one of the `flex__bottom` elements has a height different then the others, the alignment is off.

**How do we align all columns to have the same height while having the `flex__bottom` section start in the same positions?**

**Goal**:

1. Ensure all columns have the same height
2. For every item inside the `flex__bottom` should have a `border-top` that aligns with all others.

**Issue**

[image: current issue flexbox]

**Desired Output**
[image: desired output flexbox]

**Codepen is available here in case it gets difficult to replicate in the inline code snippet**

- [codepen](https://codepen.io/userrj/pen/zymKJO)

```css
/* Columns */

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .col-m-12 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 16px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-t-4 {
    width: calc(33% - 48px);
  }
}


/* Flex */

.flex__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.flex__link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.flex__top {
  padding: 16px;
}

.flex__bottom {
  border-top: 1px solid;
}


/* Image */

img {
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Lists */

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul>li {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
}


/* Link */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex__wrapper">
  <div class="col-m-12 col-t-4">
    <a class="flex__link" href="#">
      <div class="flex__top">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch" class="flex__img">
        <h2 class="flex__h2">Check back tomorrow;</h2>
        <p>I will see if the book has arrived.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex__bottom">
        <ul>
          <li>Learn More</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-m-12 col-t-4">
    <a class="flex__link" href="#">
      <div class="flex__top">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" class="flex__img">
        <h2 class="flex__h2">I am happy</h2>
        <p>I am never at home on Sundays.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex__bottom">
        <ul>
          <li>Learn More</li>
          <li>Progressively matrix</li>
          <li>Uniquely build extensible</li>
          <li>seamless customer</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-m-12 col-t-4">
    <a class="flex__link" href="#">
      <div class="flex__top">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/people" class="flex__img">
        <h2 class="flex__h2">Malls are great places to shop</h2>
        <p>I can find everything I need under one roof.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex__bottom">
        <ul>
          <li>maximizing</li>
          <li>Monotonectally whiteboard</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-m-12 col-t-4">
    <a class="flex__link" href="#">
      <div class="flex__top">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech" class="flex__img">
        <h2 class="flex__h2">I want to buy</h2>
        <p>but know it won’t suit me.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex__bottom">
        <ul>
          <li>Learn More</li>
          <li>task error-free</li>
          <li>Energistically</li>
          <li>practices</li>
          <li>ethical methodologies</li>
          <li>task error-free</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-m-12 col-t-4">
    <a class="flex__link" href="#">
      <div class="flex__top">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals" class="flex__img">
        <h2 class="flex__h2">Last Friday in three week</h2>
        <p>Blue worm shake hands with a legless lizard.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex__bottom">
        <ul>
          <li>Learn More</li>
          <li>incubate</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-m-12 col-t-4">
    <a class="flex__link" href="#">
      <div class="flex__top">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals/grayscale" class="flex__img">
        <h2 class="flex__h2">She advised</h2>
        <p>him to come back at once.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex__bottom">
        <ul>
          <li>Learn More</li>
          <li>Seamlessly</li>
          <li>build excellent</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably not that doable with pure CSS since the `flex_bottom`'s all have different parents and aren't aware of the content sizes in other flex containers. I would consider a js plugin like [matchHeights](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height). I have used a lot for this type thing and its great. don't have to write any js, just include the script and add `data-mh="rowid"` to each flex_bottom where rowid is a unique id for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can limit the amount of content in item heading and descriptions you could add a min-height to `.flex-top`.

```css
/* Columns */

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .col-m-12 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 16px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-t-4 {
    width: calc(33% - 48px);
  }
}


/* Flex */

.flex__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.flex__link {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.flex__top {
  padding: 0 16px;
  min-height: 350px;
}

.flex__bottom {
  border-top: 1px solid;
}


/* Image */

img {
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Lists */

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul>li {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
}


/* Link */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex__wrapper">
  <div class="col-m-12 col-t-4">
    <a class="flex__link" href="#">
      <div class="flex__top">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch" class="flex__img">
        <h2 class="flex__h2">Check back tomorrow;</h2>
        <p>I will see if the book has arrived.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex__bottom">
        <ul>
          <li>Learn More</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-m-12 col-t-4">
    <a class="flex__link" href="#">
      <div class="flex__top">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" class="flex__img">
        <h2 class="flex__h2">I am happy</h2>
        <p>I am never at home on Sundays.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex__bottom">
        <ul>
          <li>Learn More</li>
          <li>Progressively matrix</li>
          <li>Uniquely build extensible</li>
          <li>seamless customer</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-m-12 col-t-4">
    <a class="flex__link" href="#">
      <div class="flex__top">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/people" class="flex__img">
        <h2 class="flex__h2">Malls are great places to shop</h2>
        <p>I can find everything I need under one roof.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex__bottom">
        <ul>
          <li>maximizing</li>
          <li>Monotonectally whiteboard</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-m-12 col-t-4">
    <a class="flex__link" href="#">
      <div class="flex__top">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech" class="flex__img">
        <h2 class="flex__h2">I want to buy</h2>
        <p>but know it won’t suit me.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex__bottom">
        <ul>
          <li>Learn More</li>
          <li>task error-free</li>
          <li>Energistically</li>
          <li>practices</li>
          <li>ethical methodologies</li>
          <li>task error-free</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-m-12 col-t-4">
    <a class="flex__link" href="#">
      <div class="flex__top">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals" class="flex__img">
        <h2 class="flex__h2">Last Friday in three week</h2>
        <p>Blue worm shake hands with a legless lizard.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex__bottom">
        <ul>
          <li>Learn More</li>
          <li>incubate</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-m-12 col-t-4">
    <a class="flex__link" href="#">
      <div class="flex__top">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals/grayscale" class="flex__img">
        <h2 class="flex__h2">She advised</h2>
        <p>him to come back at once.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex__bottom">
        <ul>
          <li>Learn More</li>
          <li>Seamlessly</li>
          <li>build excellent</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, maybe grid is a better option for this layout

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  .grid__wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
  }
}

.grid__item {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  .grid__item {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  .grid__link {
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  }
}

.item__bottom {
  border-top: 1px solid;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul>li {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid__wrapper">
  <div class="grid__item">
    <a class="grid__link" href="#">
      <div>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch" class="flex__img">
        <h2>Check back tomorrow;</h2>
        <p>I will see if the book has arrived.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item__bottom">
        <ul>
          <li>Learn More</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item">
    <a class="grid__link" href="#">
      <div>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" class="flex__img">
        <h2>I am happy</h2>
        <p>I am never at home on Sundays.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item__bottom">
        <ul>
          <li>Learn More</li>
          <li>Progressively matrix</li>
          <li>Uniquely build extensible</li>
          <li>seamless customer</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item">
    <a class="grid__link" href="#">
      <div>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/people" class="flex__img">
        <h2>Malls are great places to shop</h2>
        <p>I can find everything I need under one roof.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item__bottom">
        <ul>
          <li>maximizing</li>
          <li>Monotonectally whiteboard</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item">
    <a class="grid__link" href="#">
      <div>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech" class="flex__img">
        <h2>I want to buy</h2>
        <p>but know it won’t suit me.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item__bottom">
        <ul>
          <li>Learn More</li>
          <li>task error-free</li>
          <li>Energistically</li>
          <li>practices</li>
          <li>ethical methodologies</li>
          <li>task error-free</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item">
    <a class="grid__link" href="#">
      <div>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals" class="flex__img">
        <h2>Last Friday in three week</h2>
        <p>Blue worm shake hands with a legless lizard. Blue worm shake hands with a legless lizard. Blue worm shake hands with a legless lizard. Blue worm shake hands with a legless lizard. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="item__bottom">
        <ul>
          <li>Learn More</li>
          <li>incubate</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item">
    <a class="grid__link" href="#">
      <div>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals/grayscale" class="flex__img">
        <h2>She advised</h2>
        <p>him to come back at once.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item__bottom">
        <ul>
          <li>Learn More</li>
          <li>Seamlessly</li>
          <li>build excellent</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, set height for flex__bottom

**Issue:** flex__bottom height is not specified and child elements are not even , default height: auto will adjust height according to flex__bottom elements

```
.flex__bottom {
    border-top: 1px solid;
    height: 100px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/LMgxLg